# Inline function via macro

Tags: c++, c, optimization, macros, inline

I have a recursive function which I know will only ever call itself 32 times.

```
int f(int x) { return (x == 0) ? 0 : YY + f(~x & (YY - 1)); }
```

(YY is a macro which isolates the most significant bit of x, which is not included for your sanity). For fun, I'm trying to optimize the function so I can get the best result on the UVA online judge (I would never do this optimization on real code). Is there a way to make this function into a macro / inline the function so that a function need not ever be called (i.e. the compiler expands a statement long enough that recursion is not needed), or is there a way to do this via an inline method?

Here's the macro, if needed:

```
#define YY ((((((x | (x >> 16)) | ((x | (x >> 16)) >> 8)) | (((x | (x >> 16)) | ((x | (x >> 16)) >> 8)) >> 4)) | ((((x | (x >> 16)) | ((x | (x >> 16)) >> 8)) | (((x | (x >> 16)) | ((x | (x >> 16)) >> 8)) >> 4)) >> 2)) | (((((x | (x >> 16)) | ((x | (x >> 16)) >> 8)) | (((x | (x >> 16)) | ((x | (x >> 16)) >> 8)) >> 4)) | ((((x | (x >> 16)) | ((x | (x >> 16)) >> 8)) | (((x | (x >> 16)) | ((x | (x >> 16)) >> 8)) >> 4)) >> 2)) >> 1)) ^ ((((((x | (x >> 16)) | ((x | (x >> 16)) >> 8)) | (((x | (x >> 16)) | ((x | (x >> 16)) >> 8)) >> 4)) | ((((x | (x >> 16)) | ((x | (x >> 16)) >> 8)) | (((x | (x >> 16)) | ((x | (x >> 16)) >> 8)) >> 4)) >> 2)) | (((((x | (x >> 16)) | ((x | (x >> 16)) >> 8)) | (((x | (x >> 16)) | ((x | (x >> 16)) >> 8)) >> 4)) | ((((x | (x >> 16)) | ((x | (x >> 16)) >> 8)) | (((x | (x >> 16)) | ((x | (x >> 16)) >> 8)) >> 4)) >> 2)) >> 1)) >> 1))
```

Comment: You could use a constexpr function (which can then be called at run time if you know what numbers will be fed to it when you compile it)....This method cannot be used though if the number you feed into it is determined at run time (like user input)

Comment: Actually just check this (you can look [here](http://godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:clang30,options:'-Os',source:'%23define+YY+1%0A%0Ainline+int+f(int+x)+%7B+return+(x+%3D%3D+0)+%3F+0+:+YY+%2B+f(~x+%26+(YY+-+1))%3B+%7D%0A%0Avolatile+int+x+%3D+0%3B%0Aint+main()%0A%7B++%0A++x+%3D+f(x)%3B%0A%7D')),filterAsm:(colouriseAsm:!t,commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,labels:!t),version:3) if you are skeptical) but just adding the inline directive it looks like gcc simplifies the recursion into a few simple instructions (no jumps or anything like that) (I just defined YY as 1 [it might not work thusly])

Comment: If you know x at compile time, you could write your own loop unroller, that unrolls all your recursive calls during compilation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34036608/compile-time-evaluation-of-a-c-loop

Comment: The value of x is determine during run time, but we can always guarantee the function will only recurse 32 times, because an integer is (most of the time) 32 bits.

Comment: So what does the function do?

Comment: @JacobDenson and also, you can ensure that by using `int32_t` from `stdint.h`

Comment: @DarthRubik It finds the x'th Gray code, which is a way of encoding natural numbers.

Comment: #DarthRubik My assembly is rusty, so would you mind checking my macro - I've added it to the question

Comment: Sure what is its definition?

Comment: Wow that is a monster!

Comment: Sorry using that macro and only using inline does actually cause a recursion (which is unfortunate)

Comment: I don't know if you can do what you want, but if you are using gcc you could just mark the function to be optimized for speed

Comment: If the compiler can't / won't optimize the function calls away, you can manually convert it into a iterative version

Comment: There's a lot of repetition within that macro.  The first step might be to see if the macro itself can be simplified.

Answer (score 5):

If all you want to do is convert to standard gray code, it's actually far simpler than you may realize.  All you need is to XOR the binary value with itself shifted right by one.  Here's an equivalent function (with the types declared `unsigned`), taken from the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code):

```
unsigned int binaryToGray(unsigned int num)
{
    return num ^ (num >> 1);
}
```

I compared the output to your function `f` for the first million integers, and it matched.