# Fold expressions and cout

Tags: c++, fold-expression

I have the following code that works, but I am confused about how it works.

```
template<typename ...Args>
void print(Args&&... args) {
    (std::cout << ... << std::forward<Args>(args)) << '\n';
}
int main()
{
    print(1,2.0,"3");
}
```

output:

> 123

My confusion:

I would expect 321 printed.

I would like to have this order:

```
cout << forward(args) << ...
```

but I can not get that to compile...

Comment: You did `print(1,2.0,"3");` and expected `321`?

Comment: @Holt The linked answer is not a duplicate. (incomplete for OP's post). It simply explains why there a compiler error.

Comment: @Holt, I agree that the question isn't a duplicate. At least it doesn't give an answer how to print values in the reverse order

Comment: @PiotrNycz it looks like tail (...) is couted first then head(args)

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl, the position of ... specifies left or right associativity, but doesn't change the order of arguments - it lets you choose between (std::cout << x) << y and std::cout << (x << y). The later likely would not compile

Comment: @DmitryGordon ah, that is the answer, thank you, I wish this did not get closed. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The position of `...` specifies left or right associativity, but doesn't change the order of arguments - it lets you choose between `(std::cout << x) << y` and `std::cout << (x << y)`. The later likely would not compile.

If you want to print values in the reversed order you need to use some trick. Here is the example:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct ReversePrinter
{
    ReversePrinter(T val) : val(val) { }

    template <typename U>
    ReversePrinter<T> operator<<(const ReversePrinter<U>& other) const
    {
        std::cout << other.val;
        return *this;
    }

    T val;
};

template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const ReversePrinter<T>& val)
{
    return stream << val.val;
}

template <typename... Args>
void print(Args... args)
{
    std::cout << (ReversePrinter(args) << ...);
}

int main()
{
    print(100, 200, 300.0); //prints 300200100
}
```

Comment: That's a lot of copying.

Answer (score 3):

Fold expressions respect the precedence and associativity of the operator you use. But for certain operators you can do more creative left and right folds. The only variable to account for is the sequencing of the operands. C++17 introduced a happens before relation between the right and left side of assignment operators, so they act more intuitively. The right side, and all associated side effects must happen first.

So a completely self contained solution to your question can look like this:

```
template <typename... Args>
void print(Args&& ...args) {
   int dum = 0;
   (... = (std::cout << args, dum));
}
```

Here it is, [live](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Dl82NnbKCd596PIE).

It's using a comma to print, while assigning `dum` to itself in a way that forces the evaluation order we want.

Answer (score 2):

With few trickeries, (can't come anything better at the moment) you could do following:

Not sure if there's any straight forward way

```
// Your original function
template<typename ...Args>
void print(Args&&... args) {
    (std::cout << ... << std::forward<Args>(args)) << '\n';
}

template<typename ...Args>
struct changeorder;

template<>
struct changeorder<>
{
    template<typename ...OtherArgs>
    static void invoke(OtherArgs const&... otherargs)
    {
        print(otherargs...);
    }
};

template<typename T, typename ...Args>
struct changeorder<T, Args...> 
{
    template<typename ...OtherArgs>
    static void invoke(T const& t, Args const&... args, 
                      OtherArgs const&... otherargs)
    {
        // 1st parameter send first
        changeorder<Args...>::invoke(args..., t, otherargs...);
    }
};

template<typename A, typename ...Args>
void reverseprint(A const& a, Args const&... args)
{
    changeorder<Args...>::invoke(args..., a);
}
```

[<kbd>**`Demo Here`**</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/575a30d5b4616345)

Answer (score 2):

The standard go-to solution for template-magic is [`std::index_sequence`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence).
And for making arguments indexable one uses [`std::tuple`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple).

```
template <std::size_t... N, class T>
void print_reverse_impl(std::index_sequence<N...>, std::ostream& os, T t) {
    (os << ... << std::get<std::tuple_size_v<T> - N - 1>(t));
}

template <class... T>
void print_reverse(std::ostream& os, T&&... t) {
    print_reverse_impl(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(t)>(), os, std::forward_as_tuple(t...));
}
```

Still, if you have [`static_for()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55009125) in your tool-box (you really should), this is simpler:

```
template <class... T>
void print_reverse(std::ostream& os, T&&... t) {
    static_for<sizeof...(t)>([&](auto n){
        os << std::get<sizeof...(t) - n - 1>(std::forward_as_tuple(t...));
    });
}
```

With C++20, one could also write it as:

```
void print_reverse(std::ostream& os, auto&&... t) {
    [&]<auto... N>(std::index_sequence<N...>, auto all){
        (os << ... std::get<sizeof...(t) - N - 1>(all));
    }(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(t)>(), std::forward_as_tuple(t...));
}
```

As an aside, I cut out all the calls to `std::forward`, because those rvalue-references would just be reduced down to lvalue-references by the standard-library anyway.