# How to apply operator << (or >>) to a parameter pack in C++?

Tags: c++, parameters

Imagine I have this function template:

```
template<auto& ... FLAGS>
void function(const char *c_str) {
    std::stringstream strs;
    //((strs << FLAGS)...); // <-- how do I do this?
    strs << c_str;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Consider that the function template is going to be used like this:

```
function<std::dec, std::left>("123");
```

how to apply the operator `<<` on each parameter from the parameter pack (with the object `strs` )?

I have already found a workaround with introducing a helper function:

```
void unpack(const auto& ...){};
```

And in the original function template:

```
unpack((strs << FLAGS)...);
```

But I was wondering if there is a better way to this!

Comment: [`(strs << ... << FLAGS)`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d99e8cb9dcefd819).  Form (4) on the cppreference page on [fold expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold).

Comment: also peek here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55763096/fold-expressions-and-cout

Comment: @MilesBudnek thanks. That solved the problem and very nicely so!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression

```
strs << FLAG1 << FLAG2 << FLAG3;
```

is equal to

```
(((strs << FLAG1) << FLAG2) << FLAG3);
```

You have to chain operators, therefore you need the form of fold-expression

> ( *cast-expression* ***fold-operator*** **...** ***fold-operator*** *cast-expression* )

where *fold-operator* is `stringstream::operator<<`

```
(strs << ... << FLAGS);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead a fold with the `<<` operator, you could also fold with the `,` operator, which would produce something like

```
str << FLAG1;
str << FLAG2;
...
```

(actually you'd need to use `,` instead of `;` but the resulting logic is the same).

```
template<auto& ... FLAGS>
void function(int c_str) {
    std::stringstream strs;
    ((strs << FLAGS), ...);
    //              ^
    strs << c_str;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work with some flags which require chaining